# disabling input field inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've an iframe loading a Form with input text, is it possible disable all the input just when the form is loaded into the iframe? without inserting the disable command in all the input field?
Thanks
F.

Comment: Do you have control of the source for the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iframe content comes from the same domain as the main page, you can simply use jquery :

```
$(iframe).find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Without jquery, you have to iterate over forms and their inputs :

```
for (var i=0; i<iframe.forms.length; i++) {
    var form = iframe.forms[i];
    for (var j=0; j<form.elements.length; j++) {
        form.elements[j].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello I used $('form_ifr').find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 and the iframe in the page is <iframe id="form_ifr" name="form_ifr" ... the javascript console give error $("form_ifr") is null. How can I solve?

Comment: Use `$("#form_ifr")` (note the #). And be sure to have [jquery](http://jquery.com/) imported.

Comment: I'm using ( function($) {
    $(document).ready( $('#form_ifr').find('input').attr('disabled', true));
  $(document).ready( $('#form_ifr').find('input').attr('readonly', 'readonly'));
 
} ) ( jQuery ); there are no errors on the javascript console but the input inside iframe are not disabled or readonly. The script is in the parent doc.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery, regardless of the domain of the main page: (include this in the iframe, assuming you control the source).

```
if (window!=window.top) {
    $('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it

First give an id for your form and basing that id value disable all the input fields

$(# id.input).attr("disabled","disabled");